# Official Tensorflow docs available in pdf form? (running Windows)

Tags: tensorflow

I have not been able to find pdf format docs for Tensorflow (API or tutorials).
I'm referring to the official docs, not asking for book recommendations.
Specifically pdf format, for offline local reference and study.

One problem is that I'm running Windows, so the available toolset for creating
them dynamically is limited (or different from the normally recommended tools).

But surely the pdfs must already exist online somewhere, right?

Answer (score 4):

This has been answered here. [How can you download Tensorflow API Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168716/how-can-you-download-tensorflow-api-documentation)

Essentially you can use http://devdocs.io/, which can provide you with offline access to the documentation of many libraries and languages, including Tensorflow.

Or clone the repo and type this to generate a the documentation locally. It's described in more detail in the [TensorFlow documentation.](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/documentation/)

```
$ cd tensorflow/tools/docs
$ ./gen_docs.sh              # add -a if you want C++ documentation
```

If you can't do this approach due to Windows, then versus setting up a bunch of infrastructure, it maybe easier to use the [gitbook for TF](http://haosdent.gitbooks.io/tensorflow-document/content/api_docs) then generate a PDF with toolchain as described [here](http://toolchain.gitbook.com/ebook.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ben.  I do appreciate it.  But that's why I was trying to emphasize both "PDF" and Windows.  The devdocs site does not behave as described in the info that I've seen so far (including no "enable", "offline" or "install" commands). If there is a way to generate pdf files from that page, I'd love to hear about it.  The second recommendation is a Unix shell command, is it not?

Comment: Maybe this is just easier than trying to set all that up yourself.  Use the gitbook for TF: https://haosdent.gitbooks.io/tensorflow-document/content/api_docs/ then generate a PDF with toolchain as described here: https://toolchain.gitbook.com/ebook.html I'd do it for you, but I'm on the road with only tablet.

Comment: Very nice of you to even consider doing that, Ben.  I believe Bazel was the main stumbling block to getting TF running on Windows, and it seems that it's still in 'experimental' stages.  I'll check further.  The toolchain page above lists Linux commands "sudo..."   I'll see if I can find a Windows version.  I thought this was going to be simple! :-)  Surprised that the pdfs are not online.