# How to get pdf format of tensorflow documentation?

Tags: tensorflow, pdf, documentation

I want the pdf version of tensorflow documentation, as pdf is more convenient to read and annotate.

There's [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091494/official-tensorflow-docs-available-in-pdf-form-running-windows/44091537#44091537) which is out-of-date.

This is the [source file](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs) of TF documentaion. I don't find pdf generate scripts yet. We may try to transform md/ipynb/html to a pdf, which is kind of troublesome.

Is there more straightforward and convenient way? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, KJ, I don't think this is a proper resason to reject pdf. As htmls are generate/released from  md/ipynb, we can also generate a pdf at he same time. Just like [readthedocs](https://brian2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), every big version has  pdf/html downloads (as long as html is  released)

Answer (score 2):

I write a script could generate pdf, with still some problem like TOC .

result pdf here: https://github.com/hxsnow10/tensorflow_doc_pdf

### HTML generate

```py
# change a diractoy of md and ipynb to html

import os
import pdfkit
import markdown


in_dir = 'site/en/tutorials'   # this will be relative_path"
out_dir = os.path.join("html", in_dir)
out_html_path = os.path.join(out_dir, "index.html")
out_images_path = os.path.join(out_dir, "inages")

cmd = "rm -rf {} ; mkdir -p {}".format(out_dir, out_images_path)
os.system(cmd)

cmd = "echo '' >  {}".format(out_html_path)
os.system(cmd)

files_txt = []
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(in_dir):
    # copy image to prevent relative path miss
    if 'images' in subFolders:
        path = os.path.join(root, 'images')
        m_files1 = os.listdir(out_images_path)
        m_files2 = os.listdir(path)
        if set(m_files1) & set(m_files2):
            print 'BADLLY IMGES', m_files1, m_files2
        # better to recursive merge
        cmd = "cp -rf {}/* {}".format(path, out_images_path)
        os.system(cmd)

    nb_file_paths = [os.path.join(root,filename) for filename in files if filename.endswith('.ipynb')]
    md_file_paths = [os.path.join(root,filename) for filename in files if filename.endswith('.md')]

    print "md_files = " , md_file_paths
    for file_path in md_file_paths:
        out_path = file_path[:-3]+'.html'
        markdown.markdownFromFile(
            input=file_path,
            output=out_path,
            encoding='utf8'
        )
        cmd = "cat {} >> {}".format(out_path, out_html_path)
        os.system(cmd)

    print "nb_files = " , nb_file_paths
    if nb_file_paths:
        ss = ''
        for f in nb_file_paths:
            ss = ss + ' "' + f + '"'

        cmd = 'jupyter nbconvert ' + ss + ' --to html --stdout >> {}'.format(out_html_path)
        os.system(cmd)
```

which can generate a html with images:
[image]

### PDF generate

- pdfkit.from_file can not save images, but https://html2pdf.com/ do good.
- TOC manually add e.g. https://github.com/yutayamamoto/pdfoutline TODO: TOC should be better solved by pypdf2 merge, auto getting page num.
- TODO：human organization of TOC should prepare first to merge.

I may try more if I have time.

### Links

- https://fedingo.com/how-to-convert-markdown-to-html-in-python/
- [Is there a way to convert a folder of ipynb files to a single pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389525/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-folder-of-ipynb-files-to-a-single-pdf)